# Python2 Importing | Identify Missing Library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find a way to identify missing library/libraries while importing libraries that aren't already installed by python.

I am making an application which uses some libraries that the users needs to install by themselves or by another application. For example the python-requests library. I don't want my application to install the missing dependencies and I don't have any setup script to install them. I just want a way to print the missing library/libraries to the user. Is there any way to do so? If you print the exception, it says "No module named *modulename*", and I'd like to make a custom message for it. For example "Missing library: *modulename*". Is there any way to do so?

So far importing in my code looks like this:

```
import sys, os, time, subprocess, pip
try:
    import requests
except ImportError:
    print "[!] It Seems Like You Are Missing Some Dependencies!"
    ind = str(raw_input("[*] Install Missing Dependencies? [Y/N]:"))
    ind = ind.upper()
    if 'Y' in ind:
        pip.main(['install', 'requests'])
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the Exception data into a variable, and examine the string that it returns:

```
import re  # for re.match
try:
  import requests
except ImportError as e:
  errorstring = e.args[0]
  print 'Missing library: "'+re.match(r"No module named (.+)", errorstring).group(1)+'"'
```

See [8.3. Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for a fuller description of `args`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-except block to capture the error and use the raisestatement to say the error message of your choice:

```
try:
   a = int(input()) 
except:
   raise Exception('There has been            an error in the system')
```